# PHP start loop again within another for loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

This is my simplified code (SQL Queries taken out to simplify)

```
$prizes = array('1', '2', '3', '5', '7');

// Select only 10 users for prizes
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; ++$i)
{
    // Pick a random user
    echo rand(1, 1000);
}
```

The first problem is I can't see how to include the loop within an already existing for loop and as there are only five prizes I need to start the array again for the rest of the five users. I need to include the prizes as defined in the array beneath the user.

Any pointers how?

Thanks

Comment: `$prizes = array('1', '2', '3', '5', '7'); foreach($prizes as $prize) { echo rand(1, 1000); }`

Comment: your question is a little vague, could you explain exactly what you want to achieve ? you want to give out the same price twice or what?

Comment: What's the already existing for loop? It would be easier to show you how to incorporate this if we knew the loop you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$prizes = array('1', '2', '3', '5', '7');

// make 5 draws
for ($k = 0; $k <= 5; ++$k){
// Select only 10 users for prizes
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; ++$i)
    {
        // Pick a random user
        echo rand(1, 1000);

    }
    echo $prizes[$k];
}
```

Comment: How do I use the defined prizes in $prizes rather than just going from 1-5

Comment: @AnotherUser you mean like this??

Answer (score 0):

use array shuffle and take the first 5.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

or 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

But noted in the comments, its not as random

```
$prizes = array('1', '2', '3', '5', '7');
shuffle($prizes);
// Select only 10 users for prizes
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; ++$i)
    {
    // these are your winners
    }
```